# Subtraction between columns in R

Tags: r

I have following dataframe.

| act | tar |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 3 |
| NA | NA |
| -5 | -4 |
| 0 | 0 |
| NA | 3 |

To subtract column `tar` from column `act` i used following code. But it gives me error.

```
df <- df %>%
   mutate(diff = if_else(!is.na(act) & !is.na(tar), act - tar, as.integer(NA))
```

I checked the class of both columns, and they are `integer`. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Just use `df |> mutate(diff = act - tar)`

Comment: It threw me an error saying nonnumeric argument to binary operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost right, only a little problem, the "true" and "false" conditions should be the same type, and you missied one ")"

```
     df <- df %>% mutate(diff = if_else((!is.na(act) & !is.na(tar)), as.integer(act - tar), as.integer(NA)))
 df
A data.frame: 5 × 3
act tar diff
<dbl>   <dbl>   <int>
4   3   1
NA  NA  NA
-5  -4  -1
0   0   0
NA  3   NA
```

you can also try this

```
    df <- df %>% mutate(diff = act - tar)
```

Comment: It threw me an error saying nonnumeric argument to binary operator

Comment: @learner,your columns of data are not the same type.

Comment: @learner,you can use the function class() to check it

Comment: @learner, one more thing, your code missed one ")"

Answer (score 1):

`base R` option:

```r
df <- data.frame(act = c(4, NA, -5, 0, NA),
                 tar = c(3, NA, -4, 0, 3))

df$diff <- (df$act - df$tar)
df
#>   act tar diff
#> 1   4   3    1
#> 2  NA  NA   NA
#> 3  -5  -4   -1
#> 4   0   0    0
#> 5  NA   3   NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you want to take the `NA` in account, you can write a function and `apply` that on your columns like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(act = c(4, NA, -5, 0, NA),
                 tar = c(3, NA, -4, 0, 3))

minus <- function(x) sum(x[1],na.rm=T) - sum(x[2],na.rm=T)

df$diff <- apply(df[,c('act','tar')],1, function(x) sum(x[1],na.rm=T) - sum(x[2],na.rm=T))
df
#>   act tar diff
#> 1   4   3    1
#> 2  NA  NA    0
#> 3  -5  -4   -1
#> 4   0   0    0
#> 5  NA   3   -3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(z = act - tar)

#>   act tar  z
#> 1   4   3  1
#> 2  NA  NA NA
#> 3  -5  -4 -1
#> 4   0   0  0
#> 5  NA   3 NA
```

Comment: It threw me an error saying nonnumeric argument to binary operator

Comment: I guess, @learner, that your columns are not numerical and, therefore, they need to be first convert to numeric: `df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(act, tar), as.numeric)) %>% 
  mutate(z = act - tar)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `coalesce` you can get get the Non-NA value

```
df |> 
  mutate(diff = ifelse(is.na(act - tar), coalesce(act, -tar), act - tar))
```

```
  act tar diff
1   4   3    1
2  NA  NA   NA
3  -5  -4   -1
4   0   0    0
5  NA   3   -3
```